# First Value and second last value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a table with 4 columns: worker_id,month,basic_salary.
I am trying to write a script that return worker_id, last salary date, second last basic_salary date, last salary amount (from basic_salary column).

Here's the script i wrote:

```
with cte as (
  select WORKER_ID,  (select max(month) from workers_table) last_salary
    , ROW_NUMBER()over (partition by worker_id order by month) rn
  from workers_table
  group by WORKER_ID,month
)
select *
from cte 
where rn=2
```

Here is a sample of the data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxMq3.png)

and the data I get is:

```
WORKER_ID   last_salary rn
2011-11-11  2022-01-04  2
2011-11-12  2022-01-04  2
2011-11-13  2022-01-04  2
2011-11-14  2022-01-04  2
2011-11-15  2022-01-04  2
2011-11-16  2022-01-04  2
```

The last_salary column is incorrect and i couldn't find a way to fix it and get the right results.

Comment: you need two row_numbers pone for the second last and one for the first

Comment: [No pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/512728), please. Can you [edit] your question and put the actual data in? You can make it a nice table [like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post)

Comment: I know you have an answer already but your subquery wasn't correlated. That was going to be one of the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `LEAD` window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to get the next row in the set

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      WORKER_ID,
      month,
      basic_salary,
      LEAD(month) OVER (PARTITION BY worker_id ORDER BY month) AS SecondLastSalaryDate,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY worker_id ORDER BY month) AS rn
    FROM WORKERS_TABLE
)
SELECT
  c.WORKER_ID,
  c.month AS LastSalaryDate,
  c.basic_salary As Last_basic_salary,
  c.SecondLastSalaryDate
FROM cte c
WHERE c.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below. Get your `cte` & do not use `GROUP BY`. From `cte` have self join with condition as first one having `rn = 1` and second one having `rn = 2`. Update `SELECT` statement. Please check below query.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT WORKER_ID,
           month,
           basic_salary,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY worker_id ORDER BY month) AS rn
    FROM WORKERS_TABLE
)
SELECT c1.WORKER_ID,
       c1.month AS LastSalaryDate,
       c1.basic_salary As Last_basic_salary,
       c2.month AS SecondLastSalaryDate 
FROM cte c1
    JOIN cte c2 ON c1.WORKER_ID = c2.WORKER_ID
WHERE c1.rn = 1 AND c2.rn = 2
```

Comment: Why the self-join, why not just use `LEAD`?

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, I am not an expert. I was not aware about `LEAD` so far. Thanks for your comment & answer so that I learn something new today. +1 to your answer.